# How to split one app to two apps in Django?

Tags: python, django

I made an app(first app) with Django following a tutorial.
And I finally completed a web server with AWS EC2, nginx, uwsgi, mySQL, and Django.

Then I tried to make a new app(second app).
But I found that I put account information(user model) in first app's model.py. Furthermore, I added something like notification functions in first app's model and view etc...
I want to make new app with first app's account and notification, but I am not sure it's possible to split one app to two apps.

I'd like to make a site(project) have three apps which are account apps(including user model, notification, etc.), first app, and second app. Then, I thought second app can use user info like first app. (Is there any better way?)

I just have a questions, how can I split account app from first app without any data loss. Actually I afraid that if I make a problem, it's very hard to restore it. (model, view, url, ...)

My model is following

```
class Profile(models.Model) # I'd like to split into account app
class Recruit(models.Model) # stay in first app
class Apply(models.Model) # stay in first app
class Comment(models.Model) # stay in first app
```

I will appreciate if I can get some tips or references.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create the new app
2. Move your models to them
3. Make migrations and fake migrate `migrate --fake`
4. Go to database and change the name of tables - Content types - permissions
   for help use this one by me [GITHUB script to change model names](https://github.com/amirraouf/change-django-app-name/blob/master/change_app_name.py)
5. Inform me if that worked well with you and don't expect it will be straight forward

Answer (score 1):

Don't think about the app as `isolated` entity. The concept of the app is something that you want to distribute and let other developers reuse. This is not your case.

You refer the site as `project` and it's normal to have an app to import from another app. I would suggest you call them `packages` that are part of your projects, yes you add them in your `INSTALLED_APPS` but at the end are packages.

Try to have a good packages tree where the references are top-down and not crossed referenced.

Remember:  you don't build the application for the database, you build it for the Domain, the database is just a Persistence implementation detail.

From this [article](http://blog.sapiensworks.com/post/2012/04/07/Just-Stop-It!-The-Domain-Model-Is-Not-The-Persistence-Model.aspx).